# Equal Spacing for several views using SnapKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, snapkit

How can I use snap kit to achieve the same spacing between views (and the superview for firstSubview.left and lastSubview.right) like for the bars in the picture below (and using SnapKit instead of stack view or so)?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Rather just use stackView?

Comment: As I wrote, is there an option with only snapkit and no stackview ?

Comment: You can add each of them in a view then set their width equally, then it will do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to or cannot use a `UIStackView` you can achieve the same layout by setting centerX constraints to the superview and add different multipliers for each subview:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray

        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        let numberOfLines = 8
        for _ in 0..<numberOfLines {
            let lineView = UIView()
            lineView.backgroundColor = .cyan
            containerView.addSubview(lineView)
        }

        containerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(60)
            make.left.equalTo(20)
            make.right.equalTo(-20)
            make.height.equalTo(150)
        }

        let centerXFactor: CGFloat = 2 / CGFloat(containerView.subviews.count + 1)
        containerView.subviews.enumerated().forEach { (index, lineView) in
            lineView.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
                make.top.bottom.equalTo(0)
                make.width.equalTo(4)
                make.centerX.equalTo(containerView).multipliedBy(CGFloat(index + 1) * centerXFactor)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The only "magic" here is how to calculate the `lineViews` `centerX` multipliers: You know that when you have 8 `lineViews` you'll have 9 spaces inbetween them (also counting the spaces between the `containerView`'s left and right edge and the first and last `lineView`).

To place a `lineView`'s `centerX` on the right edge of the `containerView`, you would have to set its `centerX` constraint to the `containerView`'s `centerX` constraint multiplied by 2 (You don't want to do that, but you need that value for the calculation).

Now, to get the multiplier for each lineView you divide 2 by the number of lineViews plus 1 (remember that we have one more space than we have lineViews). And then you set the `centerX` constraints on the `lineViews` as follows (for 8 `lineViews` the multiplier is 2 / 9 = 0.2222):

(pseudo code)
lineView 1: centerX = containerView.centerX multiplied by (1 * 0.2222)
lineView 2: centerX = containerView.centerX multiplied by (2 * 0.2222)
lineView 3: centerX = containerView.centerX multiplied by (3 * 0.2222)
etc.

Which gives you this:

[image]

Comment: How could we place subviews vertically?